# What is wrong using c++ copy function?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
void
copy_specs(const Cmd *cmd, std::vector<Spec> *specs)
{
    const auto _specs = cmd->get_specs();
    std::copy(_specs.begin(), _specs.end(), specs->begin());  <== crash
}
```

It crashes at the call of "std::copy". The crash point is the assignment constructor of class Spec,

```
Spec::operator=(const Spec &rhs);
```

In GDB I can see "this" is "0x0".

Then I change the code to

```
void
copy_specs(const Cmd *cmd, std::vector<Spec> *specs)
{
    const auto _specs = cmd->get_specs();
    for (const auto &spec : _specs) {
        specs->push_back(spec);
    }
}
```

It runs fine.

I am confused. What is wrong of using the copy function?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

std::copy is going to use vector as an array. You have to [resize it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve), so it can store all needed values.

You can also use [std::back_inserter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter). It will resize vector when necessary.

Comment: True but the OP may have done that and none of this explains the null pointer dereference. That's why we require a [MCVE] before we answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It looks like `std::vector::begin` of empty vector returns an iterator that points to `nullptr`. An attempt to copy the `Spec` object to `nullptr` causes null pointer dereference. OP asked `What is wrong of using the copy function?`, not asked to explain why null pointer dereference happened.

Comment: OP is obviously asking why their code crashes and doesn't comprehend that they [may] have more problems. Your answer could be incomplete. _This is why we require a [MCVE]_, so that we are not wildly guessing.

Comment: @user3188346 back_inserter solves the problem. For some reason, std::reserve() does not.